# How to create multiple target groups with specific naming conventions terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a resource that creates a target group. I would like to modify the resource with a capability of creating n number of target groups with a specific naming convention.

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "main" {
  name                          = "${var.name}-tg"
  port                          = var.forward_port
  protocol                      = var.forward_protocol
  target_type                   = var.target_type
  deregistration_delay          = var.deregistration_delay
  health_check {
    interval            = var.interval
    path                = var.path
  }
  stickiness {
    type            = var.cookie_type
  }
}
```

I want to modify it in such a way that if only one target group is created it should name it as test-tg, but if there are more than one target group then it should add index to name like test-tg1. Also each target group can have their own specific set of variable value. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Depends how you plan on creating the target groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for_each in that case as you want to create multiple TGs with different configurations. Create a variable with map(object()) type which allows you to put the values the way you expect. I have put a sample code. Take a reference of below.

Please put the values of below vars in terraform.tfvars file

cookie_type, path, deregistration_delay

var.tf

```
variable "TG_conf" {
  type = map(object({
    port              = string
    protocol          = string
    target_type       = string
    interval          = string
    cookie_type       = string
    path              = string
    deregistration_delay = string
  }))
}
```

terrafor.tfvars

```
TG_conf = {
  "test-tg" = {

    port              = 80
    protocol          = HTTP
    target_type       = "instance
    interval          = "5"
    cookie_type       = string
    path              = string
    deregistration_delay = string
  }
```

alb.tf

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "main" {
  for_each = var.TG_conf
  name                          = "${each.key}"
  port                          = each.value.port
  protocol                      = each.value.protocol
  target_type                   = each.value.target_type
  deregistration_delay          = each.value.deregistration_delay
  health_check {
    interval            = each.value.interval
    path                = each.value.path
  }
  stickiness {
    type            = each.value.cookie_type
  }
}
```