# Create n number of target groups for an application load balancer with single block in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have an ALB & want to create N number of target groups for this ALB using terraform.
All the target groups have (different) their own specific configuration like ports, healthcheck etc.
I want to create this N number of target groups with a single block of 'aws_lb_target_group'.

Creating two Target groups using individual blocks

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "alb_tg1" {
  name        = "tg1"
  port        = 8080
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = local.target_type
  vpc_id      = local.xxx

  tags = merge(
    local.common_tags,
    {
      Name           = "xxx"
      OWResourceName = "xxx"
    }
  )

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    interval = 30
    path     = /tg1
    port     = 8080
    protocol = "HTTP"
    matcher  = "200"
    timeout  = 15
  }
}
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "alb_tg2" {
      name        = "tg2"
      port        = 8090
      protocol    = "HTTP"
      target_type = local.target_type
      vpc_id      = local.xxx
    
      tags = merge(
        local.common_tags,
        {
          Name           = "xxx"
          OWResourceName = "xxx"
        }
      )
    
      health_check {
        healthy_threshold = 3
        unhealthy_threshold = 3
        interval = 25
        path     = /tg2
        port     = 8090
        protocol = "HTTP"
        matcher  = "200"
        timeout  = 16
      }
    }
```

Want to create these two TGs with single block

Was reading some other posted ask over here but did not get the desired way to do it.
ref: [How to create multiple target groups with specific naming conventions terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73992131/how-to-create-multiple-target-groups-with-specific-naming-conventions-terraform)

I was trying to achieve it use locals.tf file but seems i can not yse 'type'  of var in locals.tf hence trying to use variables.tf files
and want to assure the below is a good way to achieve it or any other good ways are there to do the same.

```
variable "tg_configs" {
  type = map
  default = {
    tg1 = {
      port = 50003
      interval=30
      timeout=15
      healthy_threshold=2
      unhealthy_threshold=2
      path=/service1
      port=50003
      protocol=HTTP
      matcher=200
    }
    tg1 = {
      port = 50004
      interval=31
      timeout=16
      healthy_threshold=3
      unhealthy_threshold=3
      path=/service2
      port=50004
      protocol=HTTP
      matcher=200
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "test" {
  for_each = var.my_tg_configs

  name        = "my-target-group-${each.key}"
  port        = each.value.port
  protocol    = each.value.protocol
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold = var.healthy_threshold
    unhealthy_threshold = var.unhealthy_threshold
    interval = var.interval
    path     = var.path
    port     = var.port
    protocol = var.protocol
    matcher  = var.matcher
    timeout  = var.timeout
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to use `for_each` or `count`. Not really sure what is your issue? Did you try anything to accomplish your goal?

Comment: Can I use for_each in a way so that all the target groups will have their own configuration, because for_each iteration can happen for only one element

Comment: Able to resolve it using multiple nested blocks per TG and then iterate them